# Protocol invoice to KT1 address?

Tags: protocol, upgrade

Can a protocol invoice direct funds to a KT1 address? We've seen them directed to tz1 addresses, but can they be directed to a KT1 (the reason being so that the recipient account can be controlled by a multi-sig contract).

I asked a core dev that worked on the variants (with invoices attached) for the last 2 proposal periods (directing would-be funds to a tz1), but he wasn't sure about KT1s, which is what we're attempting for O period.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it can. Here is an example: https://tzkt.io/KT1DUfaMfTRZZkvZAYQT5b3byXnvqoAykc43